# Rally SOAP API - How do I add an attachment to a TestCaseResult

Tags: c#, soap, rally

I have figured out how to add an attachment to TestCase, Defect objects, but I can't, using the same mechanism, seem to attach a test result file to a TestCaseResult object.  I am getting an error message of "validation error: Attachment.attachments[0] should not be null".  I've tried attaching during the creation of the test result as well as updating an existing, previously created, test result.  I would be surprised if attaching a test result file to a TestCaseResult is not supported as this is common mainstream behavior.  Thanks.

My code:

private Attachment createAttachment(string resultsFile)
        {
            byte[] bytes = readFileAsByteArray(resultsFile);

```
        // Create attachment content;
        AttachmentContent attachmentContent = new AttachmentContent();
        attachmentContent.Content = bytes;
        attachmentContent.Workspace = this.m_targetWorkspace;
        CreateResult result = m_rallyService.create(attachmentContent);
        attachmentContent = (AttachmentContent)result.Object;
        //attachmentContent = (AttachmentContent)this.m_rallyService.read(attachmentContent, this.m_targetWorkspace);


        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
        attachment.ContentType = "application / vnd.openxmlformats - officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
        attachment.Content = attachmentContent;
        attachment.Name = "Bubba.docx";
        attachment.Size = bytes.Length;
        attachment.SizeSpecified = true;
        attachment.User = this.m_rallyUser;
        //attachment.Artifact = testResult;
        attachment.Workspace = this.m_targetWorkspace;

        result = m_rallyService.create(attachment);
        attachment = (Attachment)result.Object;
        //attachment = (Attachment)this.m_rallyService.read(attachment, this.m_targetWorkspace);

        return attachment;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In deed it now works.  The Attachment object now has an attribute TestCaseResult which when set, attaches the attachment to the created result.  My revised code:

```
   private Attachment createAttachment(TestCaseResult testCaseResult, string resultsFile)
    {
        byte[] bytes = readFileAsByteArray(resultsFile);

        // Create attachment content;
        AttachmentContent attachmentContent = new AttachmentContent();
        attachmentContent.Content = bytes;
        attachmentContent.Workspace = this.m_targetWorkspace;
        CreateResult result = m_rallyService.create(attachmentContent);
        attachmentContent = (AttachmentContent)result.Object;

        // Create attachment.
        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();

        // Microsoft Word document.
        attachment.ContentType = "application / vnd.openxmlformats - officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
        attachment.Content = attachmentContent;

        // Parse out file name.
        string[] parts = resultsFile.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
        attachment.Name = parts[parts.Length - 1];

        attachment.Size = bytes.Length;
        attachment.SizeSpecified = true;
        attachment.User = this.m_rallyUser;
        attachment.TestCaseResult = testCaseResult;
        attachment.Workspace = this.m_targetWorkspace;

        result = m_rallyService.create(attachment);
        attachment = (Attachment)result.Object;

        return attachment;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you've encountered a known Defect with the Rally Webservices API. Rally Product Development is working on a fix - I'd recommend filing a case with Rally Support (rallysupport@rallydev.com) nonetheless, as this will associate your inquiry to the Defect and you'll be notified when it has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As of the 5/26/2012 Rally code release, this Defect has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If attachment belongs to the test_case_result it should use attachment.artifact:

```
Artifact
Required    false
Note    The artifact this attachment belongs to.
One-To-One Relationship Artifact
```

Why do we need Attachment.TestCaseResult instead of simple Attachment.Artifact ?

```
TestCaseResult    
Required    false
Note    Associated Test Case Result
One-To-One Relationship TestCaseResult
```

Comment: TestCaseResults are not Artifacts, they're WorkspaceDomainObjects. So you have to use the TestCaseResult attribute.