# Rally C#: Is it possible to create a new user story along with an attachment? (Avoiding to query for the user-story reference)

Tags: c#, rest, rally

Please be patient I have already gone through the example from: [How to Add an Attachment to a User Story using Rally REST .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388652/how-to-add-an-attachment-to-a-user-story-using-rally-rest-net)

However the sample code requires a query to identify the newest user story reference. The sample illustrates how to add an attachment to an existing user story. I would like to accomplish: Creating a new user story along with an attachment.

Here is my method.

```
        public void createUsWithAttachment(string workspace, string project, 
                    string userStoryName, string userStoryDescription){

        //Authenticate with Rally 
        this.EnsureRallyIsAuthenticated();

        //UserStory Setup
        DynamicJsonObject toCreate = new DynamicJsonObject();
        toCreate[RallyField.workSpace] = workspace;
        toCreate[RallyField.project] = project;
        toCreate[RallyField.name] = userStoryName;
        toCreate[RallyField.description] = userStoryDescription;

        //get the image reference - assume that this is where the image lives after being downloaded from Outlook
        String imageFilePath = "C:\\Users\\secret\\...";
        String imageFileName = "file.png";
        String fullImageFile = imageFilePath + imageFileName;
        Image myImage = Image.FromFile(fullImageFile);

        // Convert Image to Base64 format
        string imageBase64String = imageToBase64(myImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        // Length calculated from Base64String converted back
        var imageNumberBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageBase64String).Length;

        // DynamicJSONObject for AttachmentContent
        DynamicJsonObject myAttachmentContent = new DynamicJsonObject();
        myAttachmentContent["Content"] = imageBase64String;

        try
        {
            //create user story
            CreateResult createUserStory = _api.Create(RallyField.hierarchicalRequirement, toCreate);

            //create attachment
            CreateResult myAttachmentContentCreateResult = _api.Create("AttachmentContent", myAttachmentContent);
            String myAttachmentContentRef = myAttachmentContentCreateResult.Reference;
            Console.WriteLine("Created: " + myAttachmentContentRef);

            // DynamicJSONObject for Attachment Container
            DynamicJsonObject myAttachment = new DynamicJsonObject();
            //Note the below commented line
            /*myAttachment["Artifact"] = ;*/ 
            myAttachment["Content"] = myAttachmentContentRef;
            myAttachment["Name"] = "AttachmentFromREST.png";
            myAttachment["Description"] = "Attachment Desc";
            myAttachment["ContentType"] = "image/png";
            myAttachment["Size"] = imageNumberBytes;

            //create attachment
            CreateResult myAttachmentCreateResult = _api.Create("Attachment", myAttachment);
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

In the above commented line I need to get a reference to the created user story which I can do, but that would require another method to fetch the user story which I have.
However I am wondering if this can be accomplished a different way similar to how we can create a user story with the dynamicJsonObject staging.
I was thinking something like this would work, but I am having a tough time.

```
        DynamicJsonObject toCreate = new DynamicJsonObject();
        toCreate[RallyField.workSpace] = workspace;
        toCreate[RallyField.project] = project;
        toCreate[RallyField.name] = userStoryName;
        toCreate[RallyField.description] = userStoryDescription;
        toCreate["Content"] = imageToBase64;
        CreateResult createUserStory = _api.Create(RallyField.hierarchicalRequirement, toCreate);
```

My above assumption is not going as planned and I was wondering if there is a way to create a new user story with an attachment, without having to query for the userstory reference as neatly illustrated in the example from the link provided. 
Thanks and credit to the author from the example in the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should already have what you need to associate it from the create result:

```
myAttachment["Artifact"] = createUserStory.Reference;
```

Comment: Thanks Sir.
.
I am also looking into adding diverse attachment types to a user story. (.jpeg, .java, .sql, ....)
Any hints on how you would go about doing that?

Comment: The content all has to be base64 encoded, so really you just need to set the  Name and ContentType correctly and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hello Kyle: Any idea on how to upload a collection of attachments and associate with a user story.
I am trying to iterate over a directory that contains my attachments, and converting each attachment to base64.
I am just stuck on how to upload each attachment within my directory to the user story.

Comment: If you had it working for a single attachment it should be exactly the same for each file you're looping over.  There is no way to add multiple attachments at the same time in one request...